# Why am I getting two different values for $W$?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, physics

If $F=\vec{\triangledown}W$, then:

$F_x=\dfrac{\partial W}{\partial x}$ and
$F_y=\dfrac{\partial W}{\partial y}$

Therefore:

$$W=\int F_x dx = \int F_y dy$$

---

Now if we look at it in another way, we get a different result:

$$W= \int  \left(
\dfrac{\partial W}{\partial x} dx+
\dfrac{\partial W}{\partial y}dy
\right)      $$
(by multivariable chain rule)

$$=\int    \left(
F_x dx+F_y dy
\right)$$
$$=\int F_x dx+ \int F_y dy$$

This time I am getting a different result for $W$. Why am I getting contradictory results? Please explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$W = \int F_x \; dx$ just says that $W$ is an antiderivative of $F_x$ with respect to $x$, i.e. that $\dfrac{\partial W}{\partial x} = F_x$.  Using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, that translates to 
$$ W(x_1, y) - W(x_0, y) = \int_{x_0}^{x_1} F_x(x,y)\; dx$$
Note that this is all with the same $y$.
If you want to relate $W$ at two points with different $y$'s as well as different $x$'s, then you can use

$$\eqalign{ W(x_1, y_1) - W(x_0, y_0) &= W(x_1, y_1) - W(x_1, y_0) + W(x_1, y_0) - W(x_0, y_0) \cr &= 
\int_{y_0}^{y_1} F_y(x_1, y)\; dy + \int_{x_0}^{x_1} F_x(x, y_0)\; dx} $$
or more generally, for any (piecewise smooth) path $C$ from $(x_0, y_0)$ to $(x_1, y_1)$, the path integral

$$ W(x_1, y_1) - W(x_0, y_0) = \int_C \left( F_x(x,y)\; dx + F_y(x,y)\; dy\right)$$